# Слово "кулебяка"

Tags: этимология

Есть такой пирожок - кулебяка.  Но что означает это смешное название?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кулебяка (кулебака, колобака и т.д.) - пирог с рыбой, обычно открытый, реже - ватрушка.
Слово трудное, возможно от колоб - круглый хлеб, лепешка (отсюда сказочный Колобок).

Answer (score 0):

кулебяка - кулич с разной начинкой