# Происхождение слова "кулебяка"

Tags: этимология

Кулебяка — блюдо русской кухни. А что означает его название?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Происхождение слова 'кулебяка' (в старину - 'кулебака') неизвестно. Некоторые находили родство с финским словом 'кала' - 'рыба' или с немецким 'колгебекел' - 'испеченный на углях'. Владимир Даль считал, что слово произошло от глагола 'кулебячить', то есть 'валять руками'. Другие исследователи уверяли, что корень - 'колоб' (небольшой хлеб).

Хотя и неизвестно происхождение слова кулебяка, но можно думать, что это исконное русское слово. Имя собственное Кулебяка известно с 1603 г. по расходным книгам Кирилло-Белозерского монастыря, а нарицательное кулебяка — название пшеничного пирога с обильной начинкой из рыбы, капусты, каши наблюдается в письменности с 1671 г. В вятских местах в XVIII в. пироги с рыбой называли кульбаками. По имеющимся историческим материалам, кулебяка — первоначально диалектное севернорусское слово. Позднее оно приобретает общерусскую известность.

Answer (score 0):

[Повтор](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3868/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0)